# T-test for a discrete variable on a ratio scale

Tags: t-test, discrete-data

I have 20 students that take a test of 25 questions. I record the number of questions each student got correct (e.g., Sam = 10, Sarah = 13, etc.). My 20 students then take the test again a month later (e.g., Sam =9, Sarah = 15, etc.) Can I do a paired t-test to see if the classes average improved for this situation?

I'm unsure as each student has a discrete value of 0-25. I believe t-tests have to be continuous data?